Flutter FCM don't receive notification after long time in background
I added firebase fcm to my flutter app, and the notifications works perfectly.
But when i let my phone for long time say 5 or 6 hours, the app don't receive any notifications.
I tried to debig my code but the code is correct, the code is like the one in the docs.

Have you received a notification while app is killed or not running? As written in your question 'and the notifications works perfectly'.

You also need to provide a snippet of FCM code here and a little more details about your issue

I think there's been a problem with Firebase for the last 10-12 hours. If 10 people are trying to register on the system, only 2 of them are successfully registered and written to the database, while the rest are not. I haven't changed my code for a long time, and this issue started occurring since last night. Could it be a general issue with Firebase? Maybe you're experiencing something similar? maybe there is latency on firebase side?
